# angular 2 model driven nested form components

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, angular2-forms, angular2-components

**What I have:**

I am building an ionic 2 app and have built a basic angular 2 component that contains

- An input field
- A label to display the inputs title
- A label to display any validation errors

I will refer to this as my input component

I have a page component with a form on it, and currently have text inputs. 1 regular input (password) and 1 input wrapped in my input component (username).

**this is the relevant portion of my page component**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    username: ['', Validators.required],
    password: ['', Validators.required]
  });
}
```

**This is the page component template**

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

  <!-- My input component -->
  <aw-input-text id="username" name="Username" [formInput]="loginForm.controls.username"></aw-input-text>

  <!-- A standard input control -->
  <ion-item [class.error]="loginForm.controls.password.errors">
    <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" value="" name="password" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
    <p *ngIf="loginForm.controls.password.errors">This field is required!</p>
  </ion-item>

  <button type="submit" class="custom-button" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" block>Login</button>

</form>
```

**This is the template for my input component**

```
<!-- Component template -->
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>{{inputName}}</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="inputValue"></ion-input>
        <p *ngIf="!formGroup.controls.inputValue.valid">This field is required!</p>
    </ion-item>
</form>
```

**and this is the input component**

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'aw-input-text',
  templateUrl: 'build/shared/aw-input-text/aw-input-text.html'
})
export class AwInputText {

  @Input('formInput')
  public formInput;
  @Input('name')
  public inputName;
  public formGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        inputValue: this.formInput
     });
  }

}
```

The component renders correctly.

**The problem:**

The input inside the component doesn't update the valid state of the the form it is in.

When I fill out the username then the password the form becomes valid

When I fill out the password then the username the form remains invalid

So the form **can** see the valid state of the input component, it's just that the input component changing valid state doesn't trigger the form to update.

**Possible solution 1**

As described in this article and plunk

https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2

https://plnkr.co/edit/clTbNP7MHBbBbrUp20vr?p=preview

I could modify my page component to create a form group that contains a nested form group for every form control that I want to use inside of my input component

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    username: this.formBuilder.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required],
    }),
    password: ['', Validators.required],
  });
}
```

This solution fits the scenario in the article where they are adding an array of input controls, but in my case I think this feels hacky

**Possible solution 2**

Another hacky solution I have considered is using an @output directive from my input component to trigger an event on the page component that refreshes the form whenever the input component is updated.

Update to the input component

```
this.formGroup.controls.inputValue.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  this.formUpdated.emit({
    value: value
  })
});
```

Update to the page component

```
public onUpdated(value){
  this.loginForm.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

and an update the page component template

```
<aw-input-text id="username" name="Username" (updated)="onUpdated($event)" [formInput]="loginForm.controls.username"></aw-input-text>
```

This does give me the desired functionality, but I think it also seems a bit hacky having an event handler on every form page to make the input component work.

**The question**

Is there a way for me to make my component update the valid state of the form it is in (keeping in mind that I would want to re-use this component multiple times in each form) without resorting to the solution described above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the answers guys. In the end we created two components, a custom-form component and a custom-input component.

We nest as many custom-input components as we need inside the custom-form component and the custom-form component uses @ContentChildren to identify and register all the child custom-input components.

This way we don't have to pass the form into every input, and we don't have a mess of nested form groups for every input.

```
// Each CustomInputText component exposes a FormControl and 
// a control definition which has additional info about the control
@ContentChildren(CustomInputText, {descendants: true})
public customInputComponents: QueryList<CustomInputText>;

private initialised;

public ngAfterContentChecked() {
  // Only initialise the form group once
  if (!this.initialised) {
    this.initialised = true;
    this.customInputComponents.forEach((input)=>{
        this.formGroup.addControl(input.controlDefinition.id, input.formControl); 
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `@Input` your `loginForm` into nested component, as let's say `parentForm`. Then register nested `formGroup` to `parentForm` on child component init, and unregister it on child component destroy.

Comment: If anyone else needs more details about this approach, I followed [this blog post](http://brophy.org/post/nested-reactive-forms-in-angular2/) to do something similar

Answer (score 3):

What I did in my case (nested dynamic form as well) is somehow similar to Marcin's response.

I'm passing existing `FormGroup` as `parentForm` and my `Component`'s view looks like this:

```
<fieldset [formGroup]="parentForm">
    <label *ngIf="label" [attr.for]="key">{{label}}</label>
    <input [id]="key" [type]="type" [formControlName]="key" />
</fieldset>
```

It suits my needs. Hope it can help you as well.

**UPDATE:**
I've created a library for speeding up dynamic forms creation. You can take a look to figure out how I use the technique from this answer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dorf