# Reset input fields of child component on parent's form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, typescript, angular-components

> This is not a debugging problem, we're looking for the conceptual guidance on the best possible solution for the problem

In our [Angular 2 app](https://embed.plnkr.co/dZvIOdxEb05mKtEPhbgT/), we've a

- `<parent-component>` which has a `<form>`
- The `<form>` has `<level-1-child>`
- The `<level-1-child>` has `<level-2-child>`
- The `<level-2-child>` has `<textarea>`

**What we need to do?**

- Reset the `<form>` elements of `<parent-component>`, `<level-1-child>` & `<level-2-child>` on `<button>` click or submit of `<parent-component>`'s `<form>`

Here is the [issue re-producible](https://embed.plnkr.co/dZvIOdxEb05mKtEPhbgT/)

Comment: Are you using FormBuilder?

Comment: You can use @Input in child component and based on the input you can clear the form

Comment: @Chrillewoodz We're not using `FormBuilder` as of now.

Comment: hey, is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597080/how-to-reset-data-and-view-of-child-input-on-click-of-parents-button-click) the same?

Comment: You have already asked this question then why are you posting it again?

Answer (score 2):

Without `FormBuilder` it's harder to do an actual reset, but you can do something like:

Parent component:

```
<form>
  <level-1 [val]="myVal"></level-1>
</form>
```

Level 1:

```
<level-2 [val]="val"></level-2>
```

Level 2:

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="val.someProp"></textarea>
```

Then simply add `@Input() val: any` to the `level-1` and `level-2` components.

So when you "reset" you will reset the `myVal` object to its original values. This will then take effect on the children as well.

Sidenote: I'm unsure if you have to update the object reference as well for it to take effect but you can then do that with `this.myVal = Object.assign({}, this.myVal)` should you need it.

You should also call `resetForm` on the `<form>` tag when you submit. So something like:

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save()"></form>

@ViewChild('form') form;

save(): void {
  this.form.resetForm()
}
```

**EDIT:**

With `FormBuilder` you'd do:

Parent component:

```
public form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
  someProp: ''
});

<form [formGroup]="form">
  <level-1 [val]="form"></level-1>
</form>
```

Level 1:

```
<level-2 [val]="val"></level-2>
```

Level 2:

```
<div [formGroup]="val">
  <textarea formControlName="someProp"></textarea>
</div>
```

And then reset the form with `this.form.reset()`.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use `FormBuilder` to reset the forms in our code?

Comment: @xameeramir Done.

Comment: I added the code you suggested, however it is not running in [my Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dZvIOdxEb05mKtEPhbgT?p=preview)

Comment: @xameeramir I can take a look at it on monday.

Comment: I added the code you suggested, for some reasons it is not running in [my Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dZvIOdxEb05mKtEPhbgT?p=preview)

Comment: @xameeramir Look in the console, you have an error. You must add the `@Input`s.

Comment: Added the `@Input` but [it's still not working](https://plnkr.co/edit/VfDFM0VttDlPZUxhfemc?p=preview)